# chrome.storage.sync undefined error

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm writing a simple extension and need to save user blacklisted keywords. I'm using the options_page for chrome to ask users for input, and save those words to the storage to be used later. However, when I press 'save', I get the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'sync' of undefined`, but I followed the instructions in the chrome extension documentation. I added `"permissions": ["storage"]`to the manifest.json file, and reloaded the extension and options page multiple times, yet I still get the same error. Here's my javascript code:

```
var save_options = function() {
  var blacklistWords = document.getElementById('word').value;
  chrome.storage.sync.set({'blacklistWords': blacklistWords}, function() {
    // Update status to let user know options were saved.
    alert("saved");
  });
};

document.getElementById('save').addEventListener('click', save_options);
```

I would really appreciate it if someone could help me figure this out.

Comment: Want to bump this up, I'm running into the same issue.  Did you ever solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your application needs permissions to read/write sync storage.

```
"permissions": [
  "storage",
],
```

Comment: As I mentioned, I did add the storage permissions in the manifest

Comment: You must reload your application when permissions has changed.

Answer (score 0):

Always reload the extension whenever you update the `manifest.json` file.